# Strip ASP code with Preg_Replace

Tags: php, regex, asp-classic, preg-replace

I need to strip legacy ASP code from include files in a PHP app - I'm attempting to match everything between <% and %> with the regexp `/(<%([.\r\n\r])+%>)/` through preg_replace, but it's failing. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot `[.]` does not apply to all characters when inside a [character class].  Consider this one instead:

```
/(<%.+?%>)/
```

It can be read as "match <% then as few of anything as possible, followed by %>".  This lazy one won't eat the code inbetween <% ... %> and the next <% ... %>.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks. I didn't realize the dot didn't work inside character classes!

Comment: why `([^%])`, why not just `.`? Since it is lazy you don't need to exclude `%`. Also, the expression is incorrect as it will not match a string like this `<% string.Format("{0}%", percent) %>`, which is valid in ASP.

Comment: @MarathonStudios - I was the first to answer, and my expression worked in the beginning. Not sure I understand why you marked this answer.

Comment: Alex, his code matched the delimiters as well which was what I needed - and the difference in time was a few seconds. I really appreciate the answer, though!

Answer (score 0):

To mach everything between `<%` and `%>` the expression would be:

```
/<%(.*?)%>/
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using your character class correctly (I assume you're trying to match all charaters and newlines).  Try:

`/(<%(.)+?%>)/s`

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/<%(.*)%>/s', '$1', $string);
```